# Как получить год из полной даты в столбце DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

Есть даты в таком формате:

```
Data
31-01-1982
28-02-1982
31-03-1982
30-04-1982
31-05-1982
```

Тип данных: `datetime64[ns]`

Мне необходимо вернуть значение только года: то есть получить в этом DF на выходе:

```
Data
1982
1982
1982
1982
1982
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

используйте ["accessor" `df[col].dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html):

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
        Data
0 1982-01-31
1 1982-02-28
2 1982-03-31
3 1982-04-30
4 1982-05-31

In [94]: df['Data'].dt.year
Out[94]:
0    1982
1    1982
2    1982
3    1982
4    1982
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

чтобы заменить значения в столбце - даты на год:

```
df.loc[:, 'Data'] = df.loc[:, 'Data'].dt.year
```

Comment: А как мне вернуть DF а не просто значения в столбце? Я же писал, что необходимо получить такой же DF, но в другом формате

Comment: @Max52, вы хотите изменить существующий столбец или добавить новый?

Comment: Вообще просто изменить существующий

Comment: А как избавиться от выдаваемой ошибки? `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`.

Comment: @Max52, получилось избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: Боюсь, что нет.

Comment: а как вы получили этот DataFrame?

Comment: Загрузил из excel

Comment: похоже вы взяли срез или `view` от оригинального DF и пытаетесь изменять этот срез/view. Если работать с оригинальным DF такая ошибка не должна возникать...